# how to find whitespaces in char array

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, c#-4.0

```
Console.Write("Enter a string : - ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int space = 0 ;
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++) {
            if (charArray[i].Equals(" ")) {
                space = i;
            }
        }
        Console.Write(space);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I have written this code and what to know the save the index of space/white space in string.

Eg:- my input :- asd asd
     output:- 4

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the spaces than instead of using
`space = i` 
use 
`space++`
 because only then it will be able to count the number of spaces in any given string

Comment: i want to know the index where space is comming

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write("Enter a string : - ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();
        int space = 0 ;
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++) {
            if (charArray[i] == ' ') {
                space = i+1;
            }
        }
        Console.Write(space);
        Console.ReadKey();
```